# Changing quantity of 1 product unsets quantities of all other products

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I have multiple products on the page. If I change the quantity of one product, all other previously selected products quantities get reset. The quantity of previously selected products should stay same. Here is my code. if i remove dispatch line the problem resolves.

```
const addToCartHandler = async (product, type) => {
        /* getting id of product quantity field */
        var id = 'q' + product._id;
        var val = document.getElementById(id).value;

        const existItem = state.cart.cartItems.find((x) => x._id === product._id);
        var quantity;
    
        if (type == 'increment') {
            quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;
            val = parseInt(val) + 1;
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}`);
            if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
                window.alert('Product is out of stock');
                return;
             }
            dispatch({ type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM', payload: { ...product, quantity } });
            document.getElementById(id).value = val;
        } else if (type == 'decrement') {
        quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity - 1 : 0;
        val = parseInt(val) - 1;

       const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}`);
       if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
           window.alert('Product is out of stock');
           return;
       }
       dispatch({ type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM', payload: { ...product, quantity } });
    } 
};
<span className="minus" 
     onClick={(=>addToCartHandler(product,'decrement')}>
</span>
<input className="quantity"
    id={`q${product._id}`}
    value="0"

        min="0"
        type="number"
        readOnly
    />
    <span
      className="plus"
      onClick={() =>
      addToCartHandler(product, 'increment')}>+</span>
```

Here is my code of Store.js. Apparently there are no errors and it add correct product to state and cookies but quantities resets on just inout fiels.

```
 /* Store.js */
    import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
    import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
    
    export const Store = createContext();
    const initialState = {
      cart: {
        cartItems: Cookies.get('cartItems')
          ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get('cartItems'))
          : [],
        shippingAddress: Cookies.get('shippingAddress')
          ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get('shippingAddress'))
          : {},
        paymentMethod: Cookies.get('paymentMethod')
          ? Cookies.get('paymentMethod')
          : '',
      },
      userInfo: Cookies.get('userInfo')
        ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get('userInfo'))
        : null,
    };
    
    function reducer(state, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'CART_ADD_ITEM': {
          const newItem = action.payload;
          const existItem = state.cart.cartItems.find(
            (item) => item._id === newItem._id
          );
    
          const cartItems = existItem
            ? state.cart.cartItems.map((item) =>
                item.name === existItem.name ? newItem : item
              )
            : [...state.cart.cartItems, newItem];

      Cookies.set('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    }
    case 'CART_REMOVE_ITEM': {
      const cartItems = state.cart.cartItems.filter(
        (item) => item._id !== action.payload._id
      );
      Cookies.set('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    }

    case 'SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS': {
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: { ...state.cart, shippingAddress: action.payload },
      };
    }
    case 'SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD': {
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: { ...state.cart, paymentMethod: action.payload },
      };
    }
    case 'CART_CLEAR': {
      Cookies.set('selected', 0);
      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems: [] } };
    }

    case 'USER_LOGIN': {
      return { ...state, userInfo: action.payload };
    }
    case 'USER_LOGOUT': {
      return {
        ...state,
        userInfo: null,
        savedZipCode: '',
        cart: { cartItems: [], shippingAddress: {}, paymentMethod: '' },
      };
    }
   
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function StoreProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value = { state, dispatch };
  return <Store.Provider value={value}>{props.children} 
 </Store.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: I would look for the error inside the `CART_ADD_ITEM` reducer.

Comment: I checked there are no errors in CART_ADD_ITEM reducer  it adds the correct quantity in cart only problem is if I add quantity of product A let's say 3 now when I add quantity of product B say 4. Quantity of B becomes 3 in input field but quantity of product A becomes 0 in input fields in cart it stays 3 . Similarly when I add quantity of product C quantity of B will become 0. I want quantities of all the previously selected products not to change if quantity of another product changes

Comment: Is this problem due to using same onchange function for all product quantities. I think when I click on any one quantity it re renders all the inputs with same onchange function

Comment: No, the onClick function is fine, but maybe the `product` passed to `addToCartHandler` is always the same ? (Can't tell without seeing the loop context)

Comment: Are the quantities reset in the `state` or in the database?

Comment: Quantities reset on frontend....just on input field

Comment: I have edited my post to include context